# Can anyone tell me the different between these two variable assignment methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I am going through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial book and I discovered this variable assignment statement: `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token` is different than this variable assignment statement: `remember_token = cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`.  These lines are taken from this function down below used to sign users into a web application.

```
def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
end
```

Here is some additonal code to help you understand what's going on here.

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

When `sign_in(user)` is written with this: `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token` the web application allows me to sign out when I click on the sign out link, but when the variable is assigned from the left side like this: `remember_token = cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`, I can't sign out at all.  Can anyone tell me the how Rails interprets these two different assignment statements?

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It is not anything particular about Rails. If you have little knowledge of some programming language, you should notice that:

```
foo = bar
```

means to assign the calculated value of `bar` to a variable named `foo`. That is different from

```
bar = foo
```

which means to assign the calculated value of `foo` to a variable named `bar`.

Often, programming beginners confuse this `=` as assignment with `=` as equality as used in mathematics. But in programming, equality is `==`, and not `=`.

---

And in the case in your question,

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
```

is even different from a variable assignment. Assuming `cookies.permanent` is a hash, it assigning the value `remember_token` to the key `:remember_token` in that hash.

```
remember_token = cookies.permanent[:remember_token]
```

on the other hand, assigns `cookies.permanent[:remember_token]` to a variable named `remember_token`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.  Seems like a stupid, little interpretation blunder since I'm not thinking about things how a programmer would.

Answer (score 1):

Those two statements are two completely different operations.

For `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token`, you are assigning the value of the variable `remember_token` to the key in the `cookies.permanent` hash of `:remember_token`.

For `remember_token = cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`, you are retrieving the value at the key `:remember_token` in the `cookies.permanent` hash and storing it in a variable named `remember_token`.